# Client-Server PHP communication

Tags: php, webserver

How do PHP server pages handle multiple requests from different users?

I am used to C-like languages and they use multithreading. What does PHP use in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PHP interpreter is generally invoked by a webserver (like apache, lighthttpd, ...). The webserver then handles the requests (by threading, forking or whatever). Every instance of PHP is running sequentially, so there is no builtin multithreading.

There exists a PECL extension https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads which adds multithreading to PHP.

Comment: I'd just like to add to that, there also exists documentation for threading in the PHP manual: http://php.net/pthreads, in addition, there are many examples available on git and distributed with pthreads, and many useful topics in the issues list on github too, all very good reading :)

Answer (score 1):

That's really dependant upon the server you're using to handle these requests. PHP itself does not handle requests, but instead is used to parse the script and return the result. It is possible to write a web server in PHP but then again, this is all dependent on the server you are using.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a good question. Once several users try send requests to the same server , no confilct happens becuase the webserver creates an independent process, which you can call a session ( not a php session )  of it's own for each request.
PHP has nothing to do with this becuase it's only a script which is finally translated by the a machine .

Comment: PHP is not translated by some machine, it is interpreted.

Comment: And what does an interpreter do ? And finally , it is translated , think of the basic form of each computational action, with no exceptions.

Comment: translated... no. If it'd be translated, you'd have as a result for example C code which then can be compiled. A popular example for translating PHP is HipHop which translates PHP to C++.

Comment: @bwoebi Explained the translation process rather well, PHP is interpreted by the PHP interpreter because each line is evaluated as it is encountered which is the act of interpreting source code. This is common among scripting languages.

Comment: @izuriel Exactly, thank you for remembering me a definition of interpreting :-)

Comment: @izuriel technically, each line is not evaluated as it is encountered, normal execution is a two stage process; as each line is encountered it is compiled into opcodes, literals and symbols. Execution, by what is sometimes referred to as the Zend VM (though,  not really in public), is a distinct stage in the execution of a script, that occurs after all compilation has taken place. Use of the term "machine" is still pernicious, the opcodes etc that compilation creates are nothing like machine codes created when real compilation takes place. Choice terminology should probably be Virtual Machine.

Comment: We all recognize that term from our use of Java; the Zend VM is just like Java's. The appreciable difference here is that Java applications are deployed in their intermediate form, while PHP is usually distributed as plain text. Hopefully that provides some clarity :)

Comment: @JoeWatkins Well if you want to get technical, I was keeping the definition light and simple. I wouldn't go as far to say PHP runs on a VM, it has direct access to the machine that it's executed on. Interpreters are still different from VMs, But yes. The source code is compiled into an intermediate which is then interpreted - hence the reason syntax errors break the application completely.

Comment: Java has direct access to the machine too, is the jre not a VM ?? Search the php source code for VM, The Zend Engine certainly is a vm.